# Security implications of having credentials show up in HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, security, authentication

I'm currently developing a **java backend** and a **frontend using php, html and javascript** for a private project (but which I'd eventually like to open source), which means that access is limited to my LAN anyway and security does not play a vital role at the moment but might in the future.

As I'm most comfortable with coding in java most of the data processing and storage (MySQL) is handled in java and provided over http to the frontend (javascript; fetch()).

Additionally this **java backend handles** the **authentication** process which means I have to pass the login credentials with a fetch call in javascript to the backend.

As I'm not really into advanced web programming, I figured a basic POST -> REDIRECT -> GET setup for the login should suffice and I used similar login procedures (but handling the authentication in PHP) before. Therefore:

1. The client fills out a **HTML-Form** and submits it
2. The browser does a **POST request to /login** passing the **credentials** and the **target** page
3. PHP then returns the HTML containing a **javascript portion** that holds the **credentials in plain text** `login("<?php echo $_POST['username'] ?>", "<?php echo $_POST['password'] ?>", "<?php echo $_POST['target'] ?>");`
4. **Javascript** then **fetches** the **java-backend** with those **credentials** to create a session
5. Javascript issues `window.location.replace(target);` and the client is redirected to the target page (where authentication is handled via the session cookie)

I'm currently overthinking, if this is a good idea from an efficiency and security perspective. My current idea is to use the form to directly fetch the data to the backend with javascript instead of using a POST request to an additional page (skipping step 2 and 3 above):

This would mean that first of all PHP would never see the credentials (which would be one less point of failure) and that the credentials probably would not show up in the HTML. Additionally, this would cut loading times as the POST is not needed anymore.

My questions are therefore:

1. Is it bad security practice to have credentials show up in the HTML (as it is with having them in the URL, to prevent the user from accidentally sending their credentials to someone while copying the URL)? What are the risks associated with this? Could these credentials be read by any JS-libraries used or browser extensions? If so, those could probably also read the credentials which I type into the form anyway?
2. Is my alternative setup better from a security perspective (and efficiency perspective)?
3. Are there any other suggestions for improving security in this context?

Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short summary of this post and the discussion below:**

By first POSTing the credentials to PHP and then serving them back to the client in the returned HTML, **latency** (due to an additional page load) **is increased**, PHP is added as **another point of failure** and the system is theoretically opened up to **more security problems** (i.e. through javascript or browser extensions scanning the code or by hacking the PHP server).

Therefore two solutions are plausible:

1. **Skip PHP entirely** and let the login be handled by **javascript** and the **java backend** only (detailed **description** of this procedure **below** in points 1 - 5; *this is only possible as the PHP server doesn't need authentication information in this specific use case*)
2. **POST the credentials** to PHP and **let PHP communicate with the java backend** responsible for authentication, instead of reserving them to the client

**Original post:**

I don't quite understand why you think the PHP backend can't be trusted but in your scheme the PHP already gets your credentials, thanks to that original POST. If you want to avoid using PHP why not have your form call a JavaCcript function instead of POSTing to the PHP backend in the first place:

1. User enters credentials
2. User clicks "login"
3. JavaScript intercepts the login attempt, calls login()
4. JavaScript fetches `user,pass` from document body (`getElementById(...)`)
5. JavaScript contacts the Java backend which handles login

No PHP needed. But I might wonder why that's necessary - if you can't trust your own backend, what exactly are your security practices? If your PHP can't be trusted why would your Java be any better?

In your scheme you're already passing the credentials to the PHP backend in the POST request. If your concern is PHP not knowing the credentials you've already failed.

As for efficiency, your scheme has extra page loads, which will use bandwidth, maximize latency (as opposed to the goal of *minimizing* latency) and make you look incompetent to users who notice the extra redirect. JavaScript sounds like the better solution is you want to write your database code in Java.

As far as the credentials appearing in the HTML there's really no difference since the only person who could access them would be the user (who already typed them in). If they input incorrect credentials they'll only see incorrect credentials. *That said*, it violates best practice and probably isn't a good idea.

> 1. Is it bad security practice to have credentials show up in the HTML (as it is with having them in the URL, to prevent the user from accidentally sending their credentials to someone while copying the URL)? What are the risks associated with this? Could these credentials be read by any JS-libraries used or browser extensions? If so, those could probably also read the credentials which I type into the form anyway?

The answer is Yes, it's entirely bad practice and opens you up to extra risk. They're probably not too concerning but you got it exactly right - there are more places where malicious code could read the credentials, and any JS library or installed extension can read them.

> 2. Is my alternative setup better from a security perspective (and efficiency perspective)?

No and no. From the security perspective it adds another point of failure; instead of needing to hack the Java backend they could choose to hack the PHP backend instead. This wouldn't necessarily be the end of the world but *is* an extra point of failure.

> 3. Are there any other suggestions for improving security in this context?

I explained my advice above. Either suck it up and use PHP, or use JavaScript to bypass PHP entirely.

One more thing, when handling logins make sure the Java passes a secret value (unique to each session) and the server verifies that value on *every page load*. When I was working as an ethical hacker an app I tested passed an auth token (OAuth2) but the server didn't actually verify it was correct, just that the client said it was valid. Make sure the server checks anything the client does.

Also, emphasis on *unique to each session* since a secret value that stays the same for each session is definitely gonna be the worst-kept secret you've ever wished hadn't got out.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! What you line out is (at least from what I can tell) exactly my alternative solution (skipping steps 2 and 3 and using JS). As far as PHP security goes I'm not particularly concerned about someone hacking my PHP server, but as you said if it would be possible to skip PHP entirely this would increase security (at least in theory). My session id's are already generated dynamically and are invalidated after some time of inactivity automatically, but still thanks for adding that advice.

Comment: Skipping PHP is unlikely to make any actual security improvement. My main point is if you're gonna try to avoid handling credentials in PHP you should follow through. If it were my code I'd just have the PHP talk to the Java backend; that would make the design much more simple and make it harder to screw up. With this you have to make your Java backend talk to PHP anyway so why not just do the authentication without JavaScript? It still seems like you're overcomplicating the design; the client, PHP, and Java do an authentication three-way instead of making things intuitive and simple.

Comment: So you are basically saying that I have two plausible options: Either skip PHP entirely for authentication (as we've both lined out in my question and your answer) only relying on JS and java OR to handle the authentication between PHP and Java directly instead of handing it over to the client/ JS again?

The second choice could be more complicated for me to implement as I prepare the Session-Cookie in java. I'm not sure if I could route this cookie from java via PHP to the client.

Comment: Wait, if you prepare the session cookie in Java, how does the PHP verify the cookie when the user loads a page? Or does the PHP pass the cookie to Java which checks it before passing any sensitive information? This is what I mean when I say you're overcomplicating things: normally the PHP would access a database directly, without needing to call a Java backend which in turn calls a DB backend. The code complexity here is off the charts and that's likely to bite you in the ass down the road.

Comment: PHP doesn't handle any information that I need to protect. Just the construction of the layout and basic information on how some java objects need to be handled. Therefore the session is just verified in java and the clients inserts a error message if the java backend returns no data.

Comment: That makes more sense. In that case your system sounds more ridiculous than it is. That sounds like a pretty good design, actually - you can easily eliminate multiple classes of vulnerabilities at once if you do it right!